# Setting value depending on response in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in $data">
    <td data-title="'Id'" sortable="id">{{transaction.id}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Player'" sortable="playerId">{{transaction.playerId}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Type'" sortable="type">{{transaction.type}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="date">{{transaction.date | amDateFormat:'lll'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Provider'" sortable="provider">{{transaction.paymentMethod}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Amount'" sortable="amount">{{transaction.amount | currency:'€ '}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Code'" sortable="code">{{transaction.code}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Status'" sortable="status">{{transaction.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

For "transaction.code" the response from the server is 'SRV_DPS'. How do I display that as "Deposit" in the browser?

Comment: Do you want to display the string 'Deposit' instead of 'SRV_DPS' for the Code column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom filter:

JS

```
.filter('convertCode', function() {
  return function(code) {
    return (code === 'SRV_DPS') ? 'Deposit' : code;
  }
})
```

View

```
{{transaction.code | convertCode}}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/j24OgHuc0IwtIXpbeQFb?p=preview)

Comment: This is a barebones filter which I'd expect you'd make more sophisticated for other possible options. If it is as simple as a single value translation, you could consider something like what @pixelbits prescribes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want:

```
<td data-title="'Code'" sortable="code">{{transaction.code == 'SRV_DPS' ? 'Deposit' : 'Other'}}</td>
```