# How to change scope data in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a real newbie at angular. I created something now which will let me retrieve and add items via angular and get/put them in mongodb. I use express and mongoose in the app

The question is, how can i modify the data before it reaches the DOM in the controller. In this example i have created a way to retrieve data, and i get it exactly as it is stored in mongodb. What i would like is that the field where i store 1 or 0 in the database, to be shown as text. So if mongo has a value 1 i get "the value in mongo is 1" and when the field has a value of 0 get "the value is zero". (just as an example, i like other texts, but it illustrate what i want)

I post my controller, html and current output. Any help would be appreciated.

Controller

```
function getGuests($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $http.get('/api/guests')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.x = data;

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }); 

}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="getGuests">
    <div ng-repeat="guest in x">
        {{ guest.voornaam }} {{ guest.aanwezig }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The current scope output, what i see in HTML. I like to change only the value of "aanwezig" in case the value of aanwezig is 0 or 1. This can be a calcultation of things or just put a string  based on the value.

```
firstname1 1
firstname2 0
```

Something else, but would be great to learn, is how i can do a specific mongodb query by the push of a button and get that result.

Comment: This question is fairly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116286/setting-value-depending-on-response-in-angularjs/24116440#24116440 ... maybe not a duplicate but close. The second part of your question is very different than the first, so it deserves another question, on its own.

Comment: @user3314659, Thanks for your reply, it looks obvious when i look at the code. But i dont know where to put the filter in the controller exactly. Is it possible to update the code here so the complete controller from my original post is updated with the correct place where to put the filter? Any other user who can help me with this is fine also ofcourse :)   I wanted to add this comment to the answer, but i wasn't able to do this because user doesn't allow adding comments.

Comment: It doesn't go into a controller - it is a method you tack onto the module itself like you would when creating a controller, directive, service, etc. It will then be accessible in your view in the way described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom filter like :

```
.filter('formatAanwezig ', function() {
  return function(aanwezig ) {
  switch(aanwezig ) {
    case 0:
        return 'format0'
        break;
    case 1:
       return 'format1'
        break;
    default:
       return aanwezig 
} 
  }
})
```

and in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="getGuests">
    <div ng-repeat="guest in x">
        {{ guest.voornaam }} {{ guest.aanwezig | formatAanwezig  }}
    </div>
</div>
```